# Google Maps API v2 used to work on Android, now getMyLocation returns always null

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2, android-maps

I believe I did everything correct because my app used to work before. Then suddenly stop working. I am not able to get current location from Google Map object, it returns always null.

- I checked if my api key works on api console, request can be seen so I think it works
- I tried uninstalling app, then installing again, it did not help
- I tried to create a new key but this did not help neither.

I didn't post my code because I think it is correct, otherwise it wouldn't work at the beginning.​

Logcat-Errors

```
09-05 19:28:30.222: E/dalvikvm(5179): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-05 19:28:30.222: E/dalvikvm(5179): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-05 19:28:30.222: E/dalvikvm(5179): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-05 19:28:30.342: E/dalvikvm(5179): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a
```

Logcat: http://pastebin.com/RPJLr6F2

**EDIT:** I found out that cause of the problem is my device (nexus 5,Kitkat 4.4.4), it worked properly on another device(Jelly Bean 4.1)

Comment: Your location isn't given by Map but by your device's GPS or internet.

Comment: @Nabin But my location can be retrieved by map and that's what I am trying.

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: http://cdn-www.xda-developers.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Logcat.jpg

Comment: @Nabin I posted my app's log cat, some errors from All Mesagges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your logcat it is clear that your app is using a lot of memory. **[getMyLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMyLocation())** is depreciated so use **LocationClient** instead. 
From the documentation of getMyLocation():

> Returns the currently displayed user location, or null if there is no location data available.

Null is valid data returned by getMyLocation so you will need to handle it. Just check if the value returned is null.

Comment: Thank you, but as I stated my question, I found that it does not work because of my device, it works on another android device. I've already tried using LocationClient before, it worked OK on both. I am just curios why this approach does not work on my device. I will try enabling large heap and see if it solves memory problem. Thank you.

Comment: I am verifying this answer because LocationClient always works and here is the detailed answer on how to use location client:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868534/distancetomap-getmyloctation-returns-null